# JavaScript is not working if I add Thymeleaf th:field when I try to disable/enable input fields

Tags: javascript, java, html, thymeleaf

I have some input fields in my code that I need to enable or disable depending on which checkbox is clicked. It was working fine until I added the th:field part to store the value of the fields in the th:object. Now my JavaScript doesn't work, so the fields always remain disabled.

This is one of the fields in my html file:

```
<div class="form-group form-inline form-xtra required">
    <label>Texto mensaje:</label>
    <div class="form-item">
        <textarea cols="200" name="seleccionExcel" class="user-form-control 
        input-md" th:field="*{mensaje}" id="textoExcel" disabled="disabled"> 
        </textarea>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is the JavaScript file:

```
$(function() {

$(".introducirManual").click(function(){
    $('input[name="seleccionManual"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('textarea[name="seleccionManual"]').prop('disabled', false);  
    $('input[name="seleccionExcel"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[name="seleccionExcel"]').val('');
    $('textarea[name="seleccionExcel"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('textarea[name="seleccionExcel"]').val('');
});

$(".introducirExcel").click(function(){  
    $('input[name="seleccionExcel"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('textarea[name="seleccionExcel"]').prop('disabled', false);
    $('input[name="seleccionManual"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('input[name="seleccionManual"]').val('');
    $('textarea[name="seleccionManual"]').prop('disabled', true);
    $('textarea[name="seleccionManual"]').val('');
    $('input[id="numLibreta"]').val('');
});
```

});

If I remove the

> th:field="*{mensaje}"

, the script works fine again.

Should I change the way I refer to the field in my JavaScript file when using Thymeleaf?

Comment: Can you try with "th:field=${mensaje}"   ?

Comment: Thank you for your help! I have tried th:field="${mensaje.mensaje}" (because I am accesing to a variable called "mensaje" inside my "mensaje" object) and I get the same problem as with th:field="*{mensaje}".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change textarea name as below,

```
$('textarea[name="mensaje"]').prop('disabled', true);
```

Attribute **th:field** will replace attributes **value** and **name** in your input tag.

```
<textarea cols="200" name="seleccionExcel" class="user-form-control  input-md" th:field="*{mensaje}" id="textoExcel" disabled="disabled"> </textarea>
```

the above line of code is similar to:

```
<textarea cols="200" name="mensaje" class="user-form-control  input-md" id="textoExcel" disabled="disabled"> </textarea>
```